# Need to count unique incident ID #s that fall within a date range - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, filter, count, google-sheets-formula, countif

Good Afternoon,

I have a table that looks like this:

| IncidentDate | IncidentID |
| --- | --- |
| 8/12/2021 | 154541 |
| 8/14/2021 | 154542 |
| 8/14/2021 | 154543 |
| 8/17/2021 | 154544 |
| 8/18/2021 | 154545 |
| 8/18/2021 | 154545 |

I'm trying to write a formula that would count the number of unique IncidentIDs within a certain date range and display that total in a third column. In this case I am breaking down by month, but I'll also need to be able to define more specific ranges by week and by day of the week, if possible.

My apologies if I am asking too much, I am fairly new to this field.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is COUNTUNIQUEIFS and it goes like:

```
=COUNTUNIQUEIFS(B1:B, A1:A, ">=8/14/2021", A1:A, "<8/18/2021")
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That's worked perfectly for counting by month and I can already see how I can adapt it to specific weeks. Would it be possible to count incidents that occurred on Mondays (for example)?

Comment: @fcasillas yes: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbhuN.png

Comment: @fcasillas or also for mondays: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIqZJ.png